# MyODBC with MySql in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, mysql, connection, database

I want to read mysql table data to an excel file. So I decide to install MyODBC in my Ubuntu 11.04 with these command lines:

```
sudo apt-get install iodbc

sudo apt-get install libmyodbc
```

I start the iODBC Driver Manager GTK+ frontend and config ODBC drivers look like in the picture:

```
iodbcadm-gtk
```

[image]

Then I add a new USER DNS :

[image]

Try to login for DNS with User = root and Empty password give me this error :

[image]

I windows I can use ODBC without any problem.

What was I wrong and missing here? Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to connect to my database from Libre Calc and get the error :

[image]

So I changed the Server from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" and it ran well though error still occured when test connection in iODBC Management Frontend. It's weird, huh. But never mind :D